# indexOf(Element) doesn't exist for [Foo.Type] arrays

Tags: swift

Swift's `CollectionType` provides two `indexOf` methods: one that takes an element directly, and one that takes a predicate function. If I have an array of type `[Foo.Type]` (for any class `Foo`), the former doesn't exist; there's only the predicate version of `indexOf`. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `indexOf` method that takes an element requires that the element must conform to the `Equatable` protocol. It's defined in a constrained protocol extension, so it only shows up when that constraint holds true.

Metatypes (of the form `SomeType.Type`) cannot themselves conform to protocols (current as of Swift 2.1). Therefore even though you can define an == operator at global scope that operates on metatypes, you can't actually have a metatype conform to the `Equatable` protocol. This is a known language limitation.

In some cases (e.g. when using types as keys in a dictionary) you may be able to use the standard library [`ObjectIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_ObjectIdentifier_Structure/index.html) type to work around this limitation.